# FK Issue with Fact Table

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse, facttable, star-schema

I have a Datawarehouse star schema.
One Dim table is 'DimTweet'. This contains tweet details.

For a selected date I want to be able to display the number of tweets.

However, I have a problem in my current design. How do I use one TweetID as FK in the Fact tbl for multiple rows in the DimTweet tbl?

Code:

```
INSERT INTO [CarDW].[dbo].[FactCarDetail]
           ([CarID]
           ,[RegionID]
           ,[DateID]
           ,[TweetID]
           ,[SharePrice]
           ,[ShareQty]
           ,[SalesQty]
           ,[TweetCountPositive]
           ,[TweetCountNegative])
SELECT
    c.CarID,
    r.RegionID,
    d.DateKey,
    -- ????? AS TweetID
    scsp.Price,
    scsp.Quantity,
    scs.Quantity,
    -- COUNT NO. OF TWEETS Postive
    -- COUNT NO. OF TWEETS Negative
FROM 
    dbo.DimCar c        
INNER JOIN  
    dbo.StagingCarSale scs
    ON scs.CarModel = c.Model
INNER JOIN
    dbo.DimRegion r
    ON r.Region = scs.Region
INNER JOIN
    dbo.DimDate d
    ON d.Date = scs.SaleDate
--INNER JOIN
--  dbo.DimTweet t
--  ON t.
INNER JOIN  
    dbo.StagingCarSharePrice scsp
    ON scs.CarModel = scsp.CarModel
        AND scs.SaleDate = scsp.PriceDate
```

[image: DW Design]

**UPDATE: Added separate Twitter Schema** 
*Is this design feasible?*

[image]

Comment: That factTable is not at the granularity of a single tweet so tweetid doesn't belong there. What is tweet related to in it?

Comment: I am trying to add Tweets to the DW to show any possible increase or decrease in car sales/share price and effect on number of positive/negative tweets.

Answer (score 5):

I see a tweet as an event happening, so I would model it as a new fact table FactTweet. More specifically as a [factless fact](http://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/factless-fact-table/).
The dimensions for FactTweet would be DimDate, DimCar (if you can relate a tweet to a car), DimAuthor and I would probably keep URL and Description as [degenerated dimensions](http://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/degenerate-dimension/). You could potentially add the sentiment of the tweet as well (positive, negative or neutral).

DimCar and DimDate would be  [conformed dimensions](http://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/conformed-dimension/) for both FactTweet and FactCarDetail so you would be able to report on both fact in a single query.